# Django form with sections

Tags: python, django

I am creating form for editing user option in my aplication. I want the form to look like this [image]

and this how my model looks like

```
    class AboutSomeOption(models.Model)

chosen_option = models.SomeKindofField()
field1 = models.CharField()
field2 = models.CharField()
field3 = models.CharField()
field4 = models.CharField()
field5 = models.CharField()
emailAuthenticatedUser = models.OneToOneField(EmailAuthenticatedUser, one_delete = models.CASADE)
```

The user **can choose only  one option**(A, B or C). If he choose for example A. I want him to have the ability to fill the boxes associated with only option A . What is more I want to validate the fields associated with only option A.

I want to save in the model information about choosen option.

My model contains `ForeignKey` to user because each user must have the ability to edit form with options.

How do I do that?

Comment: I would do this with javascript on the page, and validation in the backend python code.

Comment: @warath-coder Javascript to disable fields for Options B, C if the user choose option A?

Comment: Yes; use javascript to handle form control. Just don't forget to validate the data in the backend (as people can disable javascript and/or send whatever data to the server regardless of the webpage control; so always validate the data again on the server.  I.e. server should not see data for field 4 and 5 if A was selected)

Comment: @warath-coder Can you add answer? I mean some example which explain how to: "server should not see data for field 4 and 5 if A was selected" and how overide validation(in my case how to set fields for 1,2,3 required true if option for example A is selected).